# Dart: Stream depends on other stream

Tags: flutter, dart, stream

I have a stream `Stream<List<String>> aStream`, it contains references.
I want a stream `Stream<List<T>> bStream` that triggers when the references change and when the content of the reference changes.

what i tried so far is:
`

```
await for(List aList in aStream){
      yield* StreamGroup.merge(aList.entries.map((String reference){
        return refrencefunction(aString);
      }));
    }
```

`

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

If `refrencefunction` returns a *Stream* for each reference, and you want to yield a `List<T>` containing all currently referenced values whenever any of the referenced values change, you'll have to manage a stream subscription for each reference, and keep a copy of the last value for each reference. Which I'm afraid won't quite fit on a single line :-)